# Downsampling an Image in Caffe

Tags: caffe

What is the best way to perform downsampling in Caffe? Does average pooling make sense?

I need to train my labels at multiple scales, and Caffe only has 1 label output. So i need a good mechanism that can downsample images correctly. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: are you downsampling image or lablel maps as well?

Comment: label maps. the label is a heatmap/segmentation map. so yeah, it should be ideally downsampled in a nice way